# Highcharts : Display static Y axis labels from array when series data is null , else auto generated label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a column graph in Highcharts. I want to display a default set of y-axis labels when the series data is all null or zero , but when series data contains some value , y axis should have auto generated labels . Please help. The json change should be used to generate labels when the series data is null.

```
function renderGraph(graphdata, isAnim) {
                var graphObj = JSON.parse(graphdata);
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    lang : {
                        numericSymbols : ["K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"]
                    }
                });
                var change = {
                    0 : '$0K',
                    2 : '$2K',
                    4 : '$4K',
                    6 : '$6K',
                    8 : '$8K'
                };
                var xAxisLegends = graphObj.bottomLegends;
                var seriesData = graphObj.seriesData;
                var xAxisLegends = graphObj.bottomLegends;
                //['Q2, 16', 'Q3, 16', 'Q4, 16', 'Q1, 17'];
                var columnColors = ["#69C3DB", "#3a8a9f"];

                var seriesData = graphObj.seriesData;
                /*[{
                name : 'Budget',
                showInLegend : false,
                data : [2, 4, 6, 8]
                }, {
                name : 'Utilisation',
                showInLegend : false,
                data : [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }];*/

                // variables which have diff values according to OS
                var chartProperties = {};
                // properties to assign to Charts's object
                var graphHeight = 0;
                // height of chart
                var graphWidth = 0;
                //Width of the column
                var pointWidth;

                // Separating the graph dimensions & styling properties as per OS name & version
                if (graphObj.osname == "iphone") {
                    chartProperties = {
                        type : 'column',
                        renderTo : 'container'
                    };
                    xAxisProp = {
                        gridLineWidth : 0,
                        categories : xAxisLegends,
                        crosshair : true
                    };
                    yAxisProp = {
                        min : 0,
                        gridLineWidth : 0,
                        tickInterval : 1,
                        title : {
                            text : ' '
                        },
                        labels : {
                            formatter : function() {
                                var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                return '$' + (this.value === 0 ? '0K' : value);                 }
                        }
                    };
                    pointWidth = 5;
                } else if (graphObj.osname == "android") {
                    chartProperties = {
                        type : 'column',
                        plotBackgroundColor : null,
                        plotBackgroundImage : null,
                        plotBorderWidth : 0,
                        plotShadow : false,
                        height : 450,
                        marginTop : 100,
                        marginLeft : 120

                    },
                    xAxisProp = {
                        categories : xAxisLegends,
                        width : 800,
                        tickmarkPlacement : 'on',
                        labels : {
                            y : 40,
                            style : {
                                color : '#333333',
                                fontSize : '25',
                                fontFamily : 'Metropolis-Light',
                                opacity : '.6'
                            },

                        }
                    };
                    yAxisProp = {
                        gridLineWidth : 0,
                        min : 0,
                        tickAmount : 5,
                        offset : 60,
                        title : {
                            text : ''
                        },
                        labels : {
                            align : 'left',
                            style : {
                                color : '#333333',
                                fontSize : '28',
                                fontFamily : 'Metropolis-Light',
                                opacity : '.5'
                            },
                            formatter : function() {
                                var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                return '$' + (this.value === 0 ? '0K' : value);
                            }
                        },

                    };
                    pointWidth = 10;
                    if (parseInt(graphObj.osversion) >= 500 && parseInt(graphObj.osversion) <= 600) {
                        graphHeight = 600;
                    } else {
                        graphHeight = 630;
                    }
                }
                $(function() {
                    new Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart : chartProperties,
                        credits : {
                            enabled : false
                        },
                        tooltip : {
                            enabled : false
                        },
                        exporting : {
                            enabled : false
                        },
                        title : {
                            text : ''
                        },
                        xAxis : xAxisProp,
                        yAxis : yAxisProp,
                        plotOptions : {
                            column : {
                                pointPadding : 0.2,
                                borderWidth : 0,
                                groupPadding : 0.38,
                                pointWidth : pointWidth
                            }
                        },
                        colors : columnColors,
                        series : seriesData
                    });

                });
            }
```

Comment: _but when series data contains some value , y axis should have auto generated labels_ where is logic for auto generated labels

Comment: @Deep3015  var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                return '$' + (this.value === 0 ? '0K' : value);                 }

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/z9r56unt/  In `this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.cal()`  `this.value` is based on the axis value in your code not on series

Comment: @Deep3015  That's where I need help . When the data in series is null , I want some default values from the JSON 'change' in code  to be displayed as y axis labels , If data is present , my logic for formatter should work .

Comment: Can you create minimal fiddle sample where you can show problem. You can modify  above fiddle which I posted earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks if there're any points with `y` value different than `0` and applies custom configuration for the y axis:

```
load: function() {
    var nonZeroPointPresent = false,
      series,
      yAxisOptions;

    // check if there're non zero points
    for (var i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++) {
      if (nonZeroPointPresent) {
        break;
      }
      if (this.series[i].points.find((p) => p.y)) {
        nonZeroPointPresent = true;
      }
    }

    // change the configuration of the axis
    if (nonZeroPointPresent) {
      yAxisOptions = {
        categories: null,
        min: null,
        max: null
      }
    } else {
      yAxisOptions = {
        categories: ['a', 'b'],
        min: 0,
        max: 1
      }
    }
    this.yAxis[0].update(yAxisOptions);
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay0Ltw9v/

Custom configuration will be used if you comment out `data: [1, 2]` line .